# SQL can you put an if statement in a select procedure?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, if-statement, procedure

I need to add an if statement to my procedure, something like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[myProcedure]
  @name VARCHAR(8000) = NULL
 ,@lname VARCHAR(8000) = NULL
 ,@flag CHAR(1) = NULL


AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
    WITH t 
    (name
    ,lname
    )

AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
    * FROM mytable
    WHERE 
  (@name IS NULL OR @name = name)
   IF @flag = 'c'
   BEGIN
      AND (@lname IS NULL OR @lname = 'Doe')
   END
   ELSE 
   BEGIN
    AND (@lname IS NULL OR @lname = lname)
   END
)
```

As you can see depending on the flag I use the lname field in one way or another.
I'm getting errors on the if section .. is it that I cannot use an if statement here? 
If not, how can I substitute the if statement?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM mytable
WHERE 
  (@name IS NULL OR @name = name)
   AND 
   (
      (@flag = 'c' AND (@lname IS NULL OR @lname = 'Doe'))
      OR 
      (@flag != 'c' AND (@lname IS NULL OR @lname = lname))
   )
```

Comment: @user712027 -- np, glad we could help!

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide an alternate answer (since I think a CASE statement is the true analog to an IF statement in SQL):

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT 
    * 
FROM 
    mytable
WHERE 
    (@name IS NULL OR @name = name)
    AND 
    (@lname is NULL OR @lname = 
    CASE 
        WHEN @flag ='c' THEN 'Doe'
        ELSE lname
    END
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
....
WHERE 
(@name IS NULL OR @name = name) AND
(
   (@flag = 'c' AND (@lname IS NULL OR @lname = 'Doe')) OR
   (@lname IS NULL OR @lname = lname)
)
```